# How to limit the VLC volume to 100%, i.e. disable over-amplification?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player

In VLC 3.0.19 (Linux) [the amplification](https://superuser.com/questions/487227/over-amplification-of-volume-in-vlc-or-any-media-player-harmful-to-speakers-or-a) goes up to '200%' (note that the UI icon and font don't exceed '125%', the on-screen display does). With my current audio hardware there's no need to use the feature.

Pressing the up  arrow <kbd>↑</kbd> increases the volume by 5% (in the mpv media player I've developed a muscle memory to skip forward with the key). I haven't been able to unbind the arrow keys, in the configuration file `~/.config/vlc/vlcrc` the functionality is now mapped to nothing:

```
# Volume up (string)
#global-key-vol-up=

# Volume up (string)
key-vol-up=

# Volume down (string)
#global-key-vol-down=

# Volume down (string)
key-vol-down=
```

I was able to disable the mouse wheel, which also controls the volume by default.

---

Additionally disabling 'remember the audio volume' option doesn't appear to work — the level of volume  is saved and persists between media files.

Answer (score 1):

Do this :

- Open menu *Tools > Preferences*
- Click on "All" at the bottom-left
- Position to *Audio > Filters > Volume normaliser*
- Set "Maximal volume level" to `1.00`.

Comment: Still goes to 200% unfortunately. Restarted VLC, the config file now reads `norm-max-level=1.000000`. There's no need to enable the normaliser itself (and how to in the first place)? But a plausible solution, I assumed it'd work.

Comment: I'll see if this is reproducible on other platforms and may file a bug for VLC.

Comment: You need to enable the Volume normalizer (see [link](https://www.videoconverterfactory.com/tips/vlc-normalize-volume.html)).

Comment: One more spot : *Preferences > All > Interface > Qt*, set "Maximum Volume displayed" to `100`.

Comment: Volume normaliser seems to not affect max volume amplification in any way. And limiting the displayed volume in Qt settings affects only the volume slider display and only if it's a default VLC-style green cone. If the _native_ volume slider style is used, then it's movement range is still 0-200%, despite the setting. In any case, none of the above affects the max volume amplification when changing the volume via mouse scroll or keyboard hotkeys. It still goes up to 200%.